# Oracle merge inside trigger using table trigger is on

Tags: oracle

I'm getting ORA-04091: mutating error

I have a trigger on tableA. Inside this trigger it uses a start & end date field on the record the trigger is running for and breaks it into how many months it spans. I then loop over each month and add the exact duplicate record to tableB if it doesn't exist or update fields if it does exist. I was trying to do that with a merge where the 'using' is tableA (the one the trigger is firing on) but this causes the error.

I could check if the record exists (:NEW) in tableB and insert/update based on that, but since that's basically what a merge command is doing, is there a way to use merge in this fashion without getting the mutating error?

Comment: I guess is there a way to have the 'using' the current record the trigger is firing for instead of the entire table?

Comment: no - merge will want to query the original table = mutation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the only information you need from `A` is the data in the row that is being modified, you can do something like

```
MERGE INTO b
 USING( SELECT :new.col1, :new.col2, :new.col3, ... , :new.colN 
          FROM dual )
    ON( ... )
...
```

That's basically the same thing that you'd do if you wanted to code a `MERGE` where the source was data from parameters passed into the procedure.

Comment: Good idea! Would be cool if Oracle just let us use :new instead as there are a ton of columns in this table but this will work. Thanks!